# java streams java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3@7291c18f

Tags: java, java-stream

I have three layers and I want to reach students names using streams from Project. I can reach them from Group. How could I do that from Project.

```
public class Student {

    private Integer id;
    private String name;
}
```

```
public class Group {

    private Long id;
    private String groupName;
    private List<Student> students;
}
```

```
public class Project {

    private Long id;
    private String title;
    private Integer numberOfGroups;
    private Integer studentsPerGroup;
    private List<Group> groups;
}
```

From Group it works fine.

```
List<Group> groupList = Arrays.asList(new Group(1L, "group#0", list));
for (Group grp : groupList)
    System.out.println(grp.getStudents().stream().map(Student::getName).collect(toList()));
```

But when I want do it from Project and run something like this:

```
List<Project> projects = Arrays.asList(new Project(0L, "Title", 5, 2, groupList));
for (Project prj : projects)
    System.out.println(prj.getGroups().stream().map(Group::getStudents).map(studentList -> studentList.stream().map(Student::getName).collect(toList())));
```

**I get this:** java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3@7291c18f

Comment: You need to use `flatMap()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I correctly understand your task, you need this stream:

```
    projects.stream()
            .map(Project::getGroups)
            .flatMap(Collection::stream)
            .map(Group::getStudents)
            .flatMap(Collection::stream)
            .map(Student::getName)
            .collect(toList());
```

With this source List:

```
    List<Project> projects = asList(
            new Project(0L, "Title", 5, 2, asList(
                    new Group(0L, "", asList(
                            new Student(1, "Smith"),
                            new Student(2, "Jackson"),
                            new Student(3, "Norris")
                    ))
            )
            )
    );
```

I got the output:

```
[Smith, Jackson, Norris]
```

Comment: thank you sir! this is exactly what I wanted to do.